# How to do relative binding for button flyout in universal windows store app

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to bind my button flyout width and height with some other control but it not working

```
    <Grid >
        <Popup IsOpen="True" Name="popup">
            <Grid Name="popupBorder" Background="Red" Height="100" Width="100" >
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
        <Button Content="check flyout" Name="btn" Click="Button_Click" >
            <Button.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <Border Name="flyoutBorder" Height="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=popupBorder, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" 
Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=popupBorder, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}">
                    </Border>
                </Flyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

I have also given datacontext to button but still same

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=localContext, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: Just a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect in a one-way binding. It is also redundant to specify `Mode=OneWay`, because that is the default value anyway. Besides that, have you tried binding to the popupBorder's ActualWidth and ActualHeight?

Comment: yes I have tried that also and I have to bind that only in but thats not working thats why I thought of binding width and height first

Comment: localContext here is the name of the page. Name="localContext".

Answer (score 0):

When you bind data in the content of `Flyout`, the binding source is in Page, and binding target is in `PopupRoot`, they have different `DataContext`, so can't it work here.

Besides, a `Flyout` control is like this:

[image]

If you place a `Border` as Content of `Flyout`, it will be placed in the `ScrollContentPresenter`:

[image]

As you can see, if you set the `Width` and `Height` of content, it will not effect the size of the `Flyout` since there is a `ScrollViewer` inside it: `ScrollViewer`'s content has unlimited height and width.

> I want to bind my button flyout width and height with some other control but it not working

So, the right way to custom the size of `Flyout` is to style the `FlyoutPresenter` for example like this:

```
<Flyout>
    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
        </Style>
    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
    <Border Name="flyoutBorder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    </Border>
</Flyout>
```

Here we need to use `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` to set the size of `Flyout`, but since you want to bind `Width` and `Height` to some other control, and **the Windows Runtime doesn't support a Binding usage for Setter.Value** (the Binding won't evaluate and the Setter has no effect, you won't get errors, but you won't get the desired result either).

Usually when need data binding in `Setter.Value`, we can create some attached dependency properties. And to solve the different `DataContext` problem, we need to define the property in code behind or view model for example like this:

```
public static double NewWidth { get; set; } = 100.0;
```

Then bind the this property to the `Width` of `popupBorder`:

```
<Grid>
    <Popup IsOpen="False" Name="popup">
        <Grid Name="popupBorder" Background="Red" Height="100" Width="{Binding NewWidth}">
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
    <Button Content="check flyout" Name="btn" Click="Button_Click" Foreground="Black">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="local:BindingBuilder.FlyoutWidth" Value="400" /> <!--This value has no meaning here, you can set it to any value.-->
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="100" />
                    </Style>
                </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Border Name="flyoutBorder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                </Border>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

To register attached property, you can for example code like this:

```cs
public class BindingBuilder : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FlyoutWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FlyoutWidth", typeof(double), typeof(BindingBuilder), new PropertyMetadata(0, OnFlyoutWidthChanged));

    public static double GetFlyoutWidth(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(FlyoutWidthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFlyoutWidth(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FlyoutWidthProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnFlyoutWidthChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double newFlyoutWidth = (double)d.GetValue(FlyoutWidthProperty);
        var presenter = (FlyoutPresenter)d;
        presenter.MinWidth = MainPageViewModel.NewWidth;
    }
}
```

Here I only attached the `MinWidth` property, you can also use the same method to custom the `MinHeight` of `FlyoutPresenter`.